# How to access Bundle from iOS static library

Tags: ios, core-data, bundle

I'm working on a static library using Core Data framework. Sadly, I'm unable to access my Bundle / .momd file generated.

What I've done :

- Create my Data Model (Model.xcdatamodeld file)
- Create a new Bundle target (named sdkResources) where I've added my xcdatamodeld file in Compile Sources and linked CoreData.framework
- Inside my sdk target, I've put sdkResources.bundle inside "Copy Bundle Resources" section
- Edit my sdk scheme and added sdkResources target in the build section

My not working code :

```
NSString *staticLibraryBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sdkResources" ofType:@"bundle"];
NSURL *staticLibraryMOMURL = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:staticLibraryBundlePath] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
_managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:staticLibraryMOMURL];
```

Returns :

```
[FAILED], NSInvalidArgumentException "Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model" raised
```

The problem seems to be the "mainBundle" access because the code below is working when I run my sdk tests (at least no error)

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSURL *staticLibraryMOMURL = [bundle URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
_managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:staticLibraryMOMURL];
```

But when I want to use my sdk inside an other App (using a podFile file) I can't access my bundle and get the same error :/

I've read and try a lot but nothing seems to work. I don't have a lot of experience in iOS dev and I'm trying my best to understand what's going on but it's a dead end to me now :(

Regards

- Edit / Screens of my project configuration

[image: Bundle build phase]

[image: sdk scheme configuration]

[image: Sdk build phase]

I don't know why sdkResources.bundle is red..
Hope this is what you're asking for, thanks.

Edit : After fixing path to sdkResources.bundle
[image]

Edit :

Ok, I'm really close to the solution, my bundle is successfully copied inside my final App but I can't access my Model and it's only working inside my sdk tests when I'm using [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] instead of [NSBundle mainBundle]. It's probably just a stupid configuration but.. yeah.. I'll keep digging !

Comment: 1.check in the finder if the bundle got copied ok

Comment: 2.NSLog the path returned for staticLibraryBundlePath

Comment: 3.NSLog staticLibraryMOMURL to check if it is ok

Comment: Sadly I can't find any traces of my sdkResources.bundle inside my final App. Where am I supposed to find it and what's the process to copy it properly ?

In my not working case, both of my staticLibBundlePath and MOMRUL are null.

Comment: make a picture of xcode when to verify you're indeed copying it to the right target. check the inspector tab and check the targets copy build phase

Comment: I've just edited my question with some screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I got it !

After (too) many hours searching to put my Model inside a Bundle I decided to just keep it inside my sdk and check my podspec configuration (since it was working in my sdk tests but not in my final project)

This is my solution, inside my podspec file I just added :

```
s.resources      = 'sdk/**/*.{xcdatamodeld,xcdatamodel}'
s.preserve_paths = 'sdk/**/*'
s.framework = 'CoreData'
```

Basically, I'm just adding my model as a resources and CoreData framework.  At least I learned a lot about Bundle and podspec configuration...

Answer (score 0):

If it is red, the file doesn't exist. If you are *sure* it exists, delete the red file and add it again: This is likely a misconfigured file link

Edit to add: often, you have to build the library first in order to generate the file. Is there a target for this library? If so, select it, build and then switch back to your project

Comment: When I've created my Bundle target, Xcode generated a 'sdkResources.bundle' file inside my "Products" group but eveything in there seems to be missing even after a successful build of my bundle. And yes, I've a target for my sdk and my bundle. My sdk needs bundle to work.

Comment: Does the file exist where you assume it does? If it does, link to it. The red link means file not found

Comment: It does and when I click on the sdkResources.bundle in the product group, I can see the "Full path" property which is correct ! How do I link to it (since it's already correct..) ? I've no control on files in the "product group" (delete, add..) Sorry, I feel so retarded right now...

Comment: Delete the red linked item and drag the good item into the same window.

Comment: Ok, I'm really close to the solution (I think...) When I manually add my sdkResources.bundle in "Copy bundle Resources" Build Phases it "pops" inside my SDK files tree BUT [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sdkResources" ofType:@"bundle"] still returns null :/

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot we see that while the bundle is meant to be copied, it doesn't exist.
=> THAT is fine it will be built later maybe

BUT

as we can also see the sdk target has no dependency to sdkResoures.
the bundle is NOT built in time

**setting it to be build in the scheme doesn't do it** (the scheme would be too late!)
**target needs to depend on the bundle target**

Comment: Ok I understand. I've added sdkResources inside "Target dependencies" of my sdk target but it still doesn't work except in my sdkTests :/ Do I miss something else ? Do I need to set something inside my podspec file for example ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is may be much simpler if you are not using Pods and using the framework only.
You will have to change the `Bundle` you are looking for your `momd` in.

Please check this article [here](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/08/25/sharing-a-core-data-model-with-a-swift-framework/)

The solution proposed is

```
    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let carKitBundle = NSBundle(identifier: "com.andrewcbancroft.CarKit")

    let modelURL = carKitBundle!.URLForResource("CarModel", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()
```

Here `com.andrewcbancroft.CarKit` the bundle identifier of your framework and that is the bundle that contains the `momd` file that you want to access from your code